# C++17 and Overloaded functions

Tags: c++, c++17

I have this project that I was trying to update so that I could use the < filesystem> header in VS2019.  When I change the "C++ Language Standard" compiler option from "Default" to "/std:c++17" the following code breaks:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CAPropertyPage :
{
public:
  struct INFO_STRUCT
  {
    INFO_STRUCT()
      : deviceType(0)
      , index(0)
    {
    };

    bool operator ==(const CAtlString &str)
    {
      return name.CompareNoCase(str) == 0;
    }

    bool operator ==(const CString &str)
    {
      return name.CompareNoCase(str) == 0;
    }

    bool operator ==(const INFO_STRUCT &is)
    {
      return name.CompareNoCase(is.name) == 0;
    }

    CString name;
    DWORD   deviceType;
    int     index;
  };
};
```

It compiles perfectly fine with Default but with /std:c++17 I get the following error message:

```
error C2535: 'bool CAPropertyPage::INFO_STRUCT::operator ==(const ATL::CAtlString &)': member function already defined or declared
message : see declaration of 'CAPropertyPage::INFO_STRUCT::operator =='
```

So the overloaded function option seems to be not supported.
Is it possible to have overloaded functions when using the /std:c++17 compiler option?

Comment: Can you give us the line numbers of where the two declarations are located?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019) seems relevant. It mentions both string types.

Comment: The error would suggest that `CAtlString` and `CString` are the exact same type under C++17, but not under the default. I would suggest getting rid of the `CAtlString` overload altogether, let the caller worry about converting any `CAtlString` objects to `CString` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Remy Lebeau for the answer.  CString and CAtlString seem to be the same thing in C++17.  When I comment out the overloaded version with CAtlString it compiles and allows the second overload because it is different.